# What semantic notions underlie 'untie, separate' with 'solve, explain'?

Tags: etymology

From *[se-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/se-#Latin)* (“away”) +‎ *[luō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/luo#Latin)* (“to untie, set free, separate”), [*solvō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solvo#Latin) originally signified

> I [loosen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loosen), [untie](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/untie), [undo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undo); [free](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/free) [up], [release](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/release), acquit, exempt

But how did it semantically broaden to signify "2. I solve, explain"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a knot. *Solvō* is the verb for working persistently at that knot until it comes undone and you have a nice, neat piece of rope again.

*Solvō* means to do that to other things too. Metaphorically, that describes the process of taking a problem apart step by step until you understand it and can *solve* it.