# What semantic notions underlie 'loosen, release' and 'able to pay all one owes'?

Tags: etymology

To wit, how does 'loosen, release' semantically shift to mean 'able to pay all one owes'?

> [Etymonline on 'solvent (adj.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/solvent?ref=etymonline_crossreference)
>
> 1650s, "able to pay all one owes," from French *solvent*,
>   from Latin *solventem* (nominative *solvens*), present participle of *solvere* "to loosen, release, accomplish, fulfill,"
>   from PIE **se-lu-*, from reflexive pronoun **s(w)e-* (see [idiom](https://www.etymonline.com/word/idiom?ref=etymonline_crossreference)) + root *[*leu-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*leu-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)* "to loosen, divide, cut apart."

I'm discombublated how ["the process of taking a problem apart step by step"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/9002/37) relates to financial solvency, if they relate at all? I read about [liquid metaphors in the world of finance](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/209112/50720).

[The CFI Institute](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/finance/solvency/) and [Zacks](https://finance.zacks.com/liquidity-vs-solvency-4979.html) outline solvency, if anyone needs a definition.

Answer (score 1):

When one owes money, one is tied to an obligation: the money has to be paid back or the matter has to be settled in some alternative way.
When everything is paid off, one is free of this obligation.
Therefore it makes a lot of sense to me that being released is a good metaphor for paying back all one owes.